# HttpWebRequest vs Add service reference

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, httpwebrequest

Can somebody please define the difference between HttpWebRequest and Adding service reference when using web services? Also what is the best approach.

Comment: What type of web service are you working with?

Comment: it is a .net web service which fetches data from sql server. and the service get called in a search page.

Comment: .NET has several styles of web services. Are you using ASMX, WCF, WCF REST, or WCF Data services? Perhaps if you could enlighten us on the version of the .NET framework you're using we could guess for you.

Comment: Sorry, It is a WCF web service, implemented in version 4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference can only be done with web service URLs (.net amsx services, wcf services, and other SOAP based services like in java,php or ruby etc). Adding a reference generates stub which contains all the classes necessary for calling web services. It includes all object types that are passed as parameters or returned from web methods.

On the other hand HttpWebRequest can be used not only to call webservices but simple aspx pages, HTML pages or any HTTP or HTTPS based urls. Its just like hitting a URL in browser.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a service reference gives you the benefit of the plumbing code necessary to call the web service methods as if you were just *calling methods*. It abstracts dealing with the request/response.

Answer (score 2):

I think in terms of performance consuming webservice through HttpWebRequest would be faster when compared with Add service reference approach as in the later case the process involves object construction at runtime & further it carries lot of other overheads (for instance other  webmethods part of web service) which you may not be using it in that particular context.

UPDATE:
Looks like my guess was wrong.
In this https://web.archive.org/web/20210619192654/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/022410-1.aspx there are some statss on SOAPcall vs service reference approach. The test revealed that service reference approach is much faster.